# Where is the documentation for http.Dir

Tags: http, go

I'm trying to set up a go file server and came across the function `http.Dir(path string) http.FileSystem` when I looked into the documentation for FileSystem.

In the source of net/http/fs.go line 705 it says:

```
//To use the operating system's file system implementation,
//
// use http.Dir:
//
//     http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp")))
```

But I can't find **any** Documentation of this function. Am I missing something?

Edit:
I missed that it's a type

Comment: It's a type, not a function: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Dir

Comment: Oh man, what a stupid mistake of me. Thank you.